# How to make the program revert back to original text without retyping it

Tags: javascript

```
if (playerChoseWeapon === true) {

    var roomGenerator = Math.Random();

    if (roomGenerator > 0.75) {

        var roomGeneratorRoomOne = Math.Random();

        if (roomGeneratorRoomOne > 0.75) {

            var rGenR1One = prompt("You see a dusty room with a door on the other side, what do you want to do? REST, DOOR, or STOP");

            if (rGenR1One === REST && playerHealthPoints < 5) {

                playerHealthPoints++;

                //Make so it goes back to original thing!

            } else if (rGenR1One === STOP) {

                alert("Script stopped, you can restart now.");

                //Maybe add some way to ask if they want to restart and it will let them?!

            } else if (rGenR1One === DOOR) {


            }
```

The code looks really ugly up there but it looks much better in my editor.

Basically have the code in the "you see a dusty room..." when you do REST, and it does it, it will revert back to the same "you see a dusty room..".

So I don't have to retype it thousands of time.

Comment: I would place that code in a function, and call it recursively.

Comment: I would put all my room descriptions in an array and have a randomRoom function pick a random number (between 0 and the length of the room array - 1) and return the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could use a do while loop:

```
if (playerChoseWeapon === true) {
    var roomGenerator = Math.Random();
        if (roomGenerator > 0.75) {
        var roomGeneratorRoomOne = Math.Random();
        if (roomGeneratorRoomOne > 0.75) {
            do{
                var rGenR1One = prompt("You see a dusty room with a door on the other side, what do you want to do? REST, DOOR, or STOP");
            if (rGenR1One === REST && playerHealthPoints < 5) {
                playerHealthPoints++;
                //Make so it goes back to original thing!
            } else if (rGenR1One === STOP) {
                alert("Script stopped, you can restart now.");
                //Maybe add some way to ask if they want to restart and it will let them?!
            } else if (rGenR1One === DOOR) {
            }
        }while(rGenR1One === REST)
```

Or like this maybe:

```
if (roomGeneratorRoomOne > 0.75) {
        var rGenR1One = prompt("You see a dusty room with a door on the other side, what do you want to do? REST, DOOR, or STOP");
        if (rGenR1One === REST && playerHealthPoints < 5) {       
            playerHealthPoints++;
            do{
                var rGenR1One = prompt("You see a dusty room with a door on the other side, what do you want to do? REST, DOOR, or STOP");
                 if (rGenR1One === REST && playerHealthPoints < 5) {
                            playerHealthPoints++;
                 }
            }while(rGenR1One === REST)
        } else if (rGenR1One === STOP) {
            alert("Script stopped, you can restart now.");
            //Maybe add some way to ask if they want to restart and it will let them?!
        } else if (rGenR1One === DOOR) {
        }
}
```